# Should INotifyPropertyChanged also be implemented on model level?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Let's say I have a view model called `MyViewModel` which is implemented like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    // BindableBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    // through the method SetProperty() which works fine.       
    private string _viewModelProperty
    public string ViewModelProperty 
    {
        get { return _viewModelProperty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _viewModelProperty, value); } 
    }

    private NestedObjectModel _nestedObject;
    public NestedObjectModel NestedObject
    {
        get { return _nestedObject; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _nestedObject, value); }
    }
}
```

As you can see it contains two properties. One string, and one object (without getting into semantics about whether a string is also an object). The object (or model) has some properties as well, but these are not directly implemented with `INotifyPropertyChanged` as the view model. It could look like this:

```
public class NestedObjectModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public double Number { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do, is to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the view model, to notify when the model changes (i.e. if either `Text` or `Number` is changed by a method in the view model). It could look something like this:

```
// This method is located in the view model
public void ChangeTextInNestedObject(string newText)
{
    NestedObject.Text = newText;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NestedObject));
}
```

Problem is, that I cannot get this to work. The value is changed, but the XAML doesn't reach to the changes. I have also tried to add a property specific notice:

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NestedObject.Text));
```

Is it not possible to do it this way? Do I really have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on model level as well?

Comment: If Model Properties are being directly  bind in XAML then yes, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The other way of binding (without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`) is --- have a wrapper properties in ViewModel which are wrapper of actual properties on object's.

Comment: Thanks @user1672994. I am binding directly to the properties (e.g. `NestedObject.Text`) from the XAML, and I would prefer not to use wrappers, since it makes the view model a mess. I just hoped it would be possible to make a general notice for the entire `NestedObject` and hence not having to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on model level.

Comment: I think model can use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: You may avoid the necessity of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the model by something like `NestedObject = new NestedObjectModel { Text = newText, Number = NestedObject != null ? NestedObject.Number : 0d };`. There is however nothing wrong with INotifyPropertyChanged in a model class.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new `NestedObject` instance in your `ChangeTextInNestedObject()` method instead of just updating the existing one? (IIRC then WPF tends to cache objects by reference, and only update subsequent / dependent bindings when the actual object instance / reference is changed)

Comment: As both @bassfader and @Clemens suggested, it is (usually) possible to create a new object and replace the old `NestedObject`. So this is a viable workaround, if one desperately wants to avoid `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I wanted the even simpler solution, but apparently that's not an option :-).

Answer (score 0):

It should work. The WPF always reacts to the `PropertyChanged` event. However, your MVVM framework perhaps compares old and new values in the `OnPropertyChanged` method, and doesn't raise an event if they are the same. Perhaps there's some parameter which forces raising the event, and if not, you can raise the `PropertyChanged` event yourself.

See this code for the viewmodel:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using WpfApp1.Model;

namespace WpfApp1.Model
{
    public class NestedObjectModel
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public double Number { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WpfApp1.ViewModels
{
    class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _viewModelProperty;
        private NestedObjectModel _nestedObject;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string ViewModelProperty
        {
            get { return _viewModelProperty; }
            set {
                _viewModelProperty = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ViewModelProperty"));
                ChangeTextInNestedObject(value);
            }
    }

    public NestedObjectModel NestedObject
    {
        get { return _nestedObject; }
        set {
            _nestedObject = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NestedObject"));
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _nestedObject = new NestedObjectModel() { Text = "TExt", Number = 321.1 };
    }

    public void ChangeTextInNestedObject(string newText)
    {
        _nestedObject.Text = newText;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NestedObject"));
    }
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <Label Content="{Binding NestedObject.Text}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding NestedObject.Number}" />
</StackPanel>
```

When you change the text in the `TextBox` the content of the first label also changes.

HTH, Tom